# Simple Longest Word problem.. but for some reason code not working and need help debugging

Tags: string, loops, cpu-word

This was the question: Have the function LongestWord(sen) take the sen parameter being passed and return the largest word in the string. If there are two or more words that are the same length, return the first word from the string with that length. Ignore punctuation and assume sen will not be empty.
Examples
Input: "fun&!! time"
Output: time
Input: "I love dogs"
Output: love

This is my code: I am pretty sure I'm doing everything right... but I'm not getting the right answer.

```
function LongestWord(sen){

var sen = sen.toLowerCase()

var string = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
var alphabet_array = string.split("")
//loop thru the sen. 

var currentWord = ""
var maxWord = ""  
var currentCount = 0 
var maxCount = 0 

for (let i = 0; i < sen.length; i++){

  var currentChar = sen[i]  

  if (currentChar !== " "){
      //we are in the middle of a word 
    if (alphabet_array.includes(currentChar)){
      currentWord += currentChar
      currentCount++ 
    }
   // console.log(currentWord)
  }
  
  
  // if not in the middle, we at the end  

  else{
    if (currentCount > maxCount){
      maxCount = currentCount 
      maxWord = currentWord
    }
  
    console.log(maxWord)
    //HAVE TO RESET YOUR CONDITIONS
    currentWord = "" 
    currentCount = 0 

  }



} //end of for loop 

return maxWord

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the max value in a list and then compare those values outside of the loop.

The script is currently only comparing the first word it sees and not waiting for it to compares max length of all the other words.
Hope it helps :)